# RIGOL Oscilloscope timescale "bug"

Tags: oscilloscope

I assume this an already known "bug" but I'm unsure if this could be fixed or not.

Straight to the problem:

I feed my RIGOL DS1054Z a 20MHz sinusoidal waveform and set the timescale to **200ms/div**. The output is the following:

[image]

(Sorry for the bad quality picture but the scope just don't want read my USB Stick for some reason.)

It is displaying the waveform just wrong! I know some other scopes have this problem as well but can this be fixed?

Note: My KEYSIGHT MSO 3000 Series displays the waveform as I would expect:

[image]

Comment: It's a poor 100MHz scope, and you are giving it 20MHz signal. Looks like an aliasing to me.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I recently used a TEKTRONIX scope one who did just the same. Is this be also a poor scope? :S

Comment: TEKTRONIX have many different models. Including "poor" ones as well :)

Comment: Is a "poor" scope worth keeping or is one high end scope enough?

Comment: It really depends on your needs.

Comment: If you are working with 20MHz signal, I believe that you should look at scopes with a higher sampling rates/bandwidth.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your help. I guess I then have to return the scope :)

Comment: Hey, don't trust just me, make some research first :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Unless "hacked", the DS1054Z is a 50MHz scope

Comment: Can someone from experience say if there is any case where you need more than four analog channels?

Comment: @d3l if you are measuring 4 analogue signals? Or even if you don't have a DSO and want to measure digital signals like SPI, then you would need all 4. The scope I have has 8 digital channels but only 2 analogue ones. I still find myself wishing I'd gone for the next one up with 4 analogue from time to time!

Comment: Anyone who says it's poor scope design doesn't understand how a digital scope works ! What you see is called subsampling or aliasing. You're trying to visualize a signal with a frequency that is too high for the current (200 ms/div) setting. That the picture is different on another scope only means that scope uses different setting. A scope is a tool, you should know it's limitations !

Comment: @d3l: "Can someone from experience say if there is any case where you need more than four analog channels?" Yes, if you want to look at 5 analog signals at the same time. Does this ever happen ? That depends on your needs. If you guarantee me that you'll never look at more than 4 analog signals simultaneuosly I'll guarantee you that a 4 channel scope is enough. Anyway if you ask about scopes with more than analog 4 channels, you have no idea what these cost ! (a lot).

Comment: @Rimpelbekkie I asked because if I have two scopes I can use up to 7 channels. My question was if one of you ever encountered a situation were you needed more than 4 channels at once!

Comment: Only 7 channels ? Geez, I bet at CERN they want to monitor at least 100 channels at the same time. Why do you let your choices be influenced by what other say or need. What matters to you is what YOU need. Will YOU ever need 7 channels or is 2 enough ? I do not not, heck probably even you do not know. Does it matter ? No because you can always buy an extra scope. It's like asking if you need a car that can do 200 km/h. Most cars can. Do you ever need it ? No, well I don't.

Comment: Try formatting your USB stick with FAT32. It should work capturing to USB stick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Keysight scope is sampling at 1 MSa/s. I can't quite make out the Rigol's sample rate, but it looks like 5 MSa/s. That might account for some of the difference. Regardless, neither of those sample rates is high enough to correctly show a 20 MHz signal. You're seeing garbage on both scopes; it's just different kinds of garbage.

Comment: But why can't the rigol display the waveform as the keysight one? Is this a software issue?

Comment: No it's a settings issue. Use identical settings (assuming this is possible, and this includes samplerate, aquiring mode etc.) and it will display the same picture.

Comment: Hm I don't get why the keysight one is better, I used the following options: RIGOL NORMAL 5.00 MSa/s , KEYSIGHT NORMAL 1.00 MSa/s both on the same timebase and free running mode. Sadly I cannot determite the memory depth of the keysight model.

Comment: WHY is the keysight better ????? Because the picture (of something you're looking at with the WRONG SETIINGS) looks better ? If you'd just learn how to use the tool then you can do the job done with the Rigol or the Keysight. I have the same Rigol at home, at work we have a 5x more BW, 12x more expensive scope. Is it better ?? 19 out of 20 times I like the Rigol better because I prefer the user interface. 1 out of 20 times I need the 500 MHz scope for the BW.

Comment: Have you considered trading in these crappy Rigol and Keysight scopes ? I mean, 100 MHz come on, that's for kids ! Anyone who's serious needs 100 GHz of bandwidth, luckily there's this one: http://teledynelecroy.com/100ghz/ Yes it's not cheap but it's the best !
OK, this is not a very serious comment, but think about it, why would you NOT need that 100 GHz scope. Maybe the Rigol is enough ? I guarantee you, on the 100 GHz scope you can also get a crap picture if you get the settings wrong.

Comment: @Rimpelbekkie Can you say where I messed up with the settings? And yeah definitely gonna buy this 100GHz scope :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24764/discussion-between-d3l-and-rimpelbekkie).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like aliasing.  Are there aliasing options on the scope? If so, turn anti aliasing on.

Comment: Didn't change anything, I just found out it works if I set the mode to "peak detect" :/

Comment: Yes, it has antialiasing options (acquire button)